# Better way of adding(SUM) 'List' of Arrays in C# using lambda expressions or LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

```
List<double[]> Patterns;
```

I am using above list to store list of patterns, here each pattern is an array of doubles ( double[] ).
Using the bellow code i am adding some patterns.

```
Patterns.Add(new double[]{1,2,3});
Patterns.Add(new double[]{1,1,1});
```

In orded to add all the patterns i am using follwing code

```
if (Patterns.Count > 0)
{
    double[] Result = new double[Patterns[0].Length];
    Patterns.ForEach((pt) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pt.Length; i++)
        {
            Result[i] += pt[i];
        }
    });
}
```

Here Result contains

> {2,3,4}

Is there a better(Less code) way of doing this? like

> double Result[] = Patterns.SomeFunction() or LINQ-Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use `Enumerable.Range` to iterate over all the relevant positions in the arrays, and then `Sum` to sum all the values for each position:

```
// Variable names changed to follow normal C# conventions
var size = patterns[0].Length;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, size)
                       .Select(index => patterns.Sum(p => p[index]))
                       .ToArray();
```

I *think* that's what you're after... of course, it will break if any of the arrays are shorter than the first one.